# Replace field value with first element of an array in the same document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

I have two models

```js
// Product model
const ProductSchema = {
  vendors: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Vendor' }],
  mainVendor: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Vendor' },
}
// Vendor model
const VendorSchema = { ... }
```

When I delete a `Vendor`, I want all `Products` with `mainVendor` field of deleted `Vendor`'s `_id` to be replaced with the first `vendor` of `vendors` array. If `vendors` array is empty, I want `mainVendor` to be set to `null`.

Say I have `Product`

```js
const product = {
  mainVendor: 'mainVendorObjectId'
  vendors: ['secondVendorObjectid', 'thirdVendorObjectId']
}
```

When I delete `Vendor` with `mainVendorObjectId` `_id`, I want my `product` to be

```js
const product = {
  mainVendor: 'secondVendorObjectId',
  vendors: ['thirdVendorObjectId']
}
```

If I have a `product` with empty `vendors` array

```js
const product = {
  mainVendor: 'mainVendorObjectId',
  vendors: []
}
```

After deleting `Vendor` with `mainVendorObjectId` `_id` I want my product to be like

```js
const product = {
  mainVendor: null,
  vendors: []
}
```

I want to run it in `post` hook.
What I have now

```js
VendorSchema.post('findOneAndDelete', async function (res: TVendorModel) {
    try {
        const products = await ProductModel.updateMany(
            { mainVendor: res._id },
            { $expr: { $set: { mainVendor: '$vendors.0' } } }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work and it won't set `mainVendor` to `null` if `vendors` array is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit long query, but you can try with Update with aggregation pipeline.

With `$cond` operator to check whether `vendors` is an empty array, if yes set `null`, else take the first value from the `vendors` array to `mainVendor` field.

For the `vendors` field, it does the same concept as `mainVendor` field, the outcome will be different in removing the first item from `vendors` array.

```
db.collection.update({
  mainVendor: "mainVendorObjectId"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      mainVendor: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$vendors",
              []
            ]
          },
          then: null,
          else: {
            $first: "$vendors"
          }
        }
      },
      vendors: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$vendors",
              []
            ]
          },
          then: [],
          else: {
            $slice: [
              "$vendors",
              1,
              {
                $size: "$vendors"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f-ptleye3EJ)

Answer (score 2):

Too late but this is my solution

`$first` extracts the first object of an array

`$ifNull` checks if $first operation is null, if true, adds null

`$slice` extracts a portion of the array

`$sum` does a sum operation. In this case is just a trick to avoid errors when the length of the array is 0 (because $slice needs a value greater than 0)

```
db.collection.update({
  "mainVendor": "mainVendorObjectId"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "mainVendor": {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            "$first": "$vendors"
          },
          null
        ]
      },
      "vendors": {
        "$slice": [
          "$vendors",
          1,
          {
            $sum: [
              {
                $size: "$vendors"
              },
              1
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```